How to automatically set the width of a flex container to its contents?
On the third line, I want the circle images to be all the way to the left while the placeholder is all the way to the right. It seems like the flex container is automatically expanding to fill the space and preventing the circle images from being next to each other.
Here's a CodePen to the work-in-progress: https://codepen.io/psychedelicseal/pen/VwoxjEg


.pokemon-card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
}

.sprite {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sprite>img {
  max-width: 85%;
  max-height: 85%;
}

.stats {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 31px 18px 20px 22px;
  gap: 3px;
}

.line-one,
.line-two,
.line-three,
.line-four {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#name {
  grid-area: name;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#form {
  grid-area: form;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: end;
}

#form>img {
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

.types {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 3px;
}

#type-one,
#type-two {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#type-one>img,
#type-two>img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#status>img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.hp-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
<div class="pokemon-card">
  <div class="sprite">
    <img src="https://archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/7/73/0015Beedrill-Mega.png">
  </div>
  <div class="stats">
    <div class="line-one">
      <div id="name">Beedrill</div>
      <div id="form">
        <img src="https://archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/c/cc/Dream_Beedrillite_Sprite.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line-two">
      Lv. 200
    </div>
    <div class="line-three">
      <div class="types">
        <div id="type-one">
          <img src="https://archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/2/26/Bug_icon_LA.png">
        </div>
        <div id="type-two">
          <img src="https://archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/b/b4/Poison_icon_LA.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="status">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/208x64">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line-four">
      <div class="hp-container">
        <div class="currentHP"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I've tried setting widths to the original grid that contains the line
.stats {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 31px 18px 20px 22px;
  gap: 3px;
}

To the line itself
.line-one, .line-two, .line-three, .line-four {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

To the flex container I want to occupy the left side of the line
.types {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 3px;
}

And to the child containers that hold the images
#type-one, #type-two {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}


Remove width: 100% from #type-one and #type-two. The elements want to be as big as the container, but shrink due to lack of space.
Set justify-content: space-between; for .line-three. Then restrict the height of the image:
.line-three {
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#status>img {
    max-height: 2em;
    max-width: 100%;
}



.pokemon-card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
}

.sprite {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sprite>img {
  max-width: 85%;
  max-height: 85%;
}

.stats {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 31px 18px 20px 22px;
  gap: 3px;
}

.line-one,
.line-two,
.line-three,
.line-four {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.line-three {
justify-content: space-between;
}

#name {
  grid-area: name;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#form {
  grid-area: form;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: end;
}

#form>img {
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

.types {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 3px;
}

#type-one,
#type-two {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#type-one>img,
#type-two>img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#status>img {
  max-height: 2em;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.hp-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
<div class="pokemon-card">
  <div class="sprite">
    <img src="https://archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/7/73/0015Beedrill-Mega.png">
  </div>
  <div class="stats">
    <div class="line-one">
      <div id="name">Beedrill</div>
      <div id="form">
        <img src="https://archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/c/cc/Dream_Beedrillite_Sprite.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line-two">
      Lv. 200
    </div>
    <div class="line-three">
      <div class="types">
        <div id="type-one">
          <img src="https://archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/2/26/Bug_icon_LA.png">
        </div>
        <div id="type-two">
          <img src="https://archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/b/b4/Poison_icon_LA.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="status">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/208x64">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line-four">
      <div class="hp-container">
        <div class="currentHP"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




That doesn't resolve the issue. The image is only 20x20 but the container (#type-one, #type-two) remains at ~48x20. Sorry maybe my question was unclear. I want the flex container to not expand beyond the image.

Do you mean the gap of 3px in the class .types?

@Seal - Can you explain which browser you're testing in? The behaviour of Chromium and Firefox is different.

@Alohci - I am testing in Firefox.

@Rico - No, I want there to be a gap between the elements, but the child containers are being stretched to fill the parent container. This is the behavior I want to prevent.

I have edited the answer. The size of the image needs to be limited. Run my code snippet. Does this answer the question?
